# can't get IIS FTP server working - alway closes the connection immediately

Tags: ftp

we have a small conveyancing business with a little win10 lan of five machines.
Is that good enough to meet your business environment requirement?
If so:
i'd like to put ftp on it somewhere so I set up iis ftp server on one.
but all I ever can get is 'server closed the connection' whenever i try to ftp to the site.
I've tried from localhost via ftp on cmd and via address bar on firefox and from filezilla on that same machine and via ftp from terminal sessions on a couple of remote linux mint machines.
all machines seem to make the connection alright but report it gets immediately closed.
I switched off the firewall for a test and that didn't fix it so it's not the firewall.
I can ping the IP okay whenever.
We have a static IP.

Comment: Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Don't only report on client-side issues, also show relevant server configuration & settings, log and/or error messages. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: Typical FTP issues are: clients default to anonymous FTP while most servers don't. FTP over SSL is not default behaviour for most FTP clients, so expect issues when your server mandates SSL. - But without detail of your server is configured it's a guessing game